# How to find sprite center in pygame python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6.5 on win32 and I want to find the center of my sprite to position it on the x axis exactly how I want it to be. I there any way to do this?

Extra information: pip version 18.0, Computer Dell Inspiron 15, 3000 Series. I loaded the sprite using the `pygame.image.load()` function.

Comment: You know the sprite's size and position reference (one corner).  I'm unclear where you're stuck.  Post a code snippet and refer to variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
pygame.image.load()
```

Only load the image. You'll maybe have to define your image size with

```
pygame.transform.scale()
```

if your image resolution is already defined, you won't need it and you can use two variables to indicate your image width and height.

In python, X and Y position start at top left. So top left of your window would be (0,0) and bottom right would be (window_width, window_height). It is the same thing for all your element in your code.

This code print the center of sprite (or any image):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800  #define size of window
display_height = 600

img_pos_x = 100     #define position of image
img_pos_y= 100

img_size_x = 40     #define size of image
img_size_y = 40

img = pygame.image.load("image.png")                        #load image
img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(img_size_x,img_size_y))   #resize image
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height)) #display window
gameExit = False

screen.blit(img, (img_pos_x,img_pos_y)) #display image

img_center = (img_pos_x + img_size_x/2, img_pos_y + img_size_y/2) #find image center

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():    #define what to do when game not quit
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    print(img_center)       #print coordinates of image center
```

This code can be modified for different usage, this one is just to show how it works. Hope you can understand what I mean.

EDIT: for clarification and correction

this line:

```
img_center = (img_pos_x + img_size_x/2, img_pos_y + img_size_y/2)
```

find top left coordinate (x, y) of image, the top right is x + image width so the middle would be half the image width and we find middle coordinate by adding half image width to top left coordinate. Same thing for Y coordinate, both (X,Y) would point to middle of any image.